# How to solve a transcendal equation

Tags: equation-solving

I want to get the solution `x` of this equation

```
a (-(1/(1 + b c + a x)) - Log[b c + a x] + Log[1 + b c + a x]) - d = 0
```

in terms of `a, b, c, d`. `Solve` and `FindRoot` do not give any answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear[a, b, c, x, d, r]
eq1 = a (-(1/(1 + b c + a x)) - Log[b c + a x] + Log[1 + b c + a x]) - d == 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To simplify, make common sub-expression substitution

```
eq2 = eq1 /. (b c + a x) -> z
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Write it as

```
eq2 = (-(1/(1 + z)) - Log[z] + Log[1 + z]) == d/a
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq3 = eq2 /. (d/a) -> r
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now take the exponential

```
eq4 = Exp[#] & /@ eq3
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq5 = eq4 /. {(1 + z) -> k, z -> k - 1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now reduce comes to help. We can either use Reduce on Reals or not. For the general case

```
Reduce[eq5, k]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using the last case for example:

```
eq6 = k == 1/(1 + ProductLog[C[1], -E^(-1 - r)])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now start back substitution

```
 eq7 = eq6 /. {k -> 1 + z, r -> (d/a)}
 eq8 = eq7 /. z -> (b c + a x)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now solve for x

```
 Solve[eq8, x]
 (*x -> (-1 - b c + 1/(1 + ProductLog[C[1], -E^(-1 - d/a)]))/a *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But notice there is arbitrary parameters `C[1]` which is an integer. So there are infinite number of solutions. Also, the other Reduce results are still applicable in this final solution